# Get the 'img' src recovery path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='prod/images/1.jpg'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='prod/images/2.jpg'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='prod/images/3.jpg'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='prod/images/4.jpg'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I would like to recovery the value of `src` attribute and it assign to variable.

I found this:

```
var srcPath = item.closest("tr").find('img[src*="nameOFpath"]');
```

But this use to find not to assign value.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to assign `src` of all `img` in variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery methods **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** or **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get attribute value.

Use closest `td` to get specific `img` (if you use `tr` in closest it will return always first `img` *"prod/images/1.jpg"*) :

```
var src_value = item.closest("td").find('img').prop('src');
//Or
var src_value = item.closest("td").find('img').attr('src');
```

Or if you already have a variable that contain all tds `$tds` use :

```
var src_value = $tds.closest("td").find('img').attr('src');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Concrectly var src_value = $tds.closest("td").find('img').attr('src'); to works in my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var srcPath = item.closest("tr").find('img[src*="nameOFpath"]');
srcPath.attr('src', 'yourNewValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
var imgSrc = srcPath.attr("src");
```

and just like that the img src is going to be stored in the imgSrc variable